# Raspberry PI Zero W browsers (Chromium, Midori, Kweb, Epiphany) choppy playing videos. Any better options?

Tags: video, streaming-video, noobs, pi-zero-w, web-browsers

Basically, my project includes displaying **high-quality**

- images
- videos
- different files like text, pdf etc..

on raspberry **pi zero W**. What is the best OS suitable for this application?

I have used NOOBS and tried displaying in browser mode but the video playing is more choppy (in chromium, Midori, Epiphany, Kweb etc).

Comment: High-quality = 480p, 720p, 1080p, 4K ?

Comment: images, videos with 1080p or 4k

Comment: And you have made a search for info regarding this?

Comment: yes! I did. Best I could find is [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/33472/html5-video-options) and [this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/51195/what-operating-system-web-browser-supports-html5-video-with-hardware-acceleratio?rq=1). My aim is to display them as a slideshow. Thinking of any other better approach rather than displaying through a browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [info-beamer](http://www.info-beamer.com) ? On a Pi Zero , dedicated digital signage software will be necessary to achieve
fluid transitions. Regular browsers will not cut it.

Comment: Hi yes, I found there are many digital signage softwares available in the market, but first I wanted to try it on my own so I did it using a browser. Is there any open source software with which I can achieve hardware acceleration, video decoding like Kodi or any plugins to browsers on Pi

Comment: info-beamer and others have an open-source tier. You can try it all you want , for free.

Comment: @Sneha Did you get it working with Infobeamer? I'm working on a very very similar project making a web app to showcase my files using Angular CLI. The problem is using Angular CLI kills off my Pi zero. I need a lighter solution to the problem. Was info beamer worth it?

Comment: @Clinkz I haven't tried info-beamer. I first tried writing a bash script for my slideshow using feh and omxplayer packages. It worked.

Comment: @Sneha Do you have a github repo that I could check out? My [browser solution](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/88779/angular-app-renders-rpi-zero-unresponsive) isn't working either. Considering using FEH with Nodejs.

Comment: @Clinkz No, sorry I don't have a GitHub repo. I don't think pi zero can handle web applications, try using 3B+ if you are only dealing with images. Other option would be using feh packages via bash script that allows you to display images or you can try out info beamer.

Comment: @Sneha Yeah. I guessed it. Performance for images/videos on a simple web app is really really bad. My web app does start eventually but it becomes unresponsive quite often. I'm trying to port my code to nodejs to download the content and show them via info-beamer. Lets see.

Comment: @Sneha update to the project, infobeamer won't work because I have to scale down my images using `sharp` on nodejs which is a minor unnecessary overhead not to mention it decreases picture quality. That's only the images. Videos don't even open! After a couple of weeks' worth of coding, I'm doing what you did. `Feh` and `omxplayer` but not through bash, through `nodejs`.